# Reasons why Letter_opener would not work anymore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I have a Rails project and i'm working on 2 computers ( MacBook and Imac ).
Suddenly letter_opener stopped to work on MacBook.
I recently updated both computers's Xcode, ruby version etc ...
It still working on the Imac, so it's not about the project configuration or any codes. The repo are up to date on both computers.

I tried to uninstall/reinstall Letter_opener but it still not working. I also tried to install Mail Catcher but i can't make it to work.

What can i check ? I'm afraid to have the issue on Imac in the futur!

- ruby 2.5.3
- Rails 5.2.3
- 'letter_opener', '~> 1.7'

Comment: Search if there is a similar issue reported here or open a new issue https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/issues/new

Comment: Also, please try to specify the versions of Rails, ruby and letter-opener you are using.

Comment: It looks like it's depending of the browser set as default. It's still not working on Chrome but working on Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Embarrassingly, it was because I forgot to uncomment the 'confirmable' section in the devise migration file and add :confirmable to the users model (so the email I expected letter_opener to open simply wasn't sending in the first place).

Presuming you didn't forget these things, [this](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/issues/178#issuecomment-805309850) comment may help, namely:

```rb
# development.rb
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

then try to send an email, then check logs for an error.

The commenter says:

> you probably have not configured the from address for that particular email. In my case error was located in Devise configuration which used to lack sender config.